# Configure new installed WordPress in live server

Tags: themes, installation

i've just installed wordpress from my cpanel with hostgator. so this is the scenario: my static html site was hosted here : www.mydomain.com and i  installed wordpress in on same path now i am able to login to my dashboard and activate new theme but when i click visit website that takes me to same html version my question is how do i configure my site that instead of loading that html site it takes me to WordPress site for mydomain.com. if i remove files for html site will it automatically render WordPress site when i or do i need some configurations for this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this is because you have a index.html (from your static site) and a index.php (from WordPress).

So if you rename your index.html to something like: oldindex.html, the correct index.php will be shown (the WordPress index.php).

Alternatively, you could remove the index.html.